# "Beveled" Shapes in Quartz 2D

Tags: iphone, graphics, quartz-2d, shapes, bevelled

I'm familiar with some of the basics of Quartz 2D drawing, like drawing basic shapes and gradients and so on, but I'm not sure how to draw a shape with a "beveled" look, like this:

[beveled circle http://www.shaggyfrog.com/junk/beveled-circle.jpg](http://www.shaggyfrog.com/junk/beveled-circle.jpg)

Essentially we've got a shine on one corner, and maybe some shading in the opposite corner. I think -- I didn't make this image, although I'd like to be able to approximate it.

Any ideas? This is on the iPhone, and I'd like to use built-in frameworks and avoid any external libraries if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are really only a few useful approaches you can take to this problem.

1. Use your basic shape drawing techniques and combine them with a one or more gradient curves. (Implicit object construction) with curves/fills.
2. Custom build a UIView and build the object up per-pixel in a drawRect.
3. Pre-render your beveled/shadowed shapes and load them into an image and blit them into a UIImageView.